# What's the difference between the span-x classes and the 'column' class in blueprint-css?

Tags: html, css, blueprint-css

The definition I found for the blueprint css class called `.column` says:

```
.column Use with .span-x classes to create combinations of columns in the layout.
```

But the `span-x` classes seem to overlap this functionality since they allow columns to be defined without referring to `.column`?

Could someone explain what distinguishes these two classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the .column class has been dropped. it used to be used with .span-x to define a column but the css was updated so that a div with a .span-x defined a column by itself.

see line 100 at http://github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css/blob/e9e91bb94a0f498e63359556b2301cfd18400377/blueprint/screen.css

the column class is the same as any div with a span-x

take a look at http://www.blueprintcss.org/ for the latest version.

Josh